# Allow all characters in ItemNameValidation setting

Tags: packages, validation

Trying to install a package which has the item names with characters like `(', '.', ')`.

How can I temporarily disable `ItemNameValidation` setting? Tried changing the setting to `'.*'` which did not help.

Sitecore version - 9.1.1

Comment: did you try to leave the `ItemNameValidation` setting empty?

Comment: @TamásTárnok yes, did not help.

Comment: try:  `(.*?)` (see this for details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6711971/regular-expressions-match-anything)

Comment: @AdamHess Still the same.

Comment: Can the contents of the package be modified to contain the altered name?

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 settings that control item names during package installation:

`InvalidItemNameChars` should be blank.

`ItemNameValidation` should be `.*`

With this settings you should be able to install package with any item names.

Comment: Stil the same error, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following patch:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <settings>    
      <setting name="ItemNameValidation">
        <patch:attribute name="value">^.*$</patch:attribute>
      </setting>
   </settings>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

The regex means that:

`^` start of the string

`.*` It matches any character.

`*` Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible.

`$` End of the string